# PhP pulling string from line and separating by ":"

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pull a string from a .txt file using php, I have done that successfully using this code:

```
$f_contents = file("accounts/00183.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
$data = $line;
```

After my random string is pulled I would like it to be separated.

e.g All strings in the .txt are in this format "User:Pass".

Im trying to make "$first" = to the content before the ":" e.g "User".
and then "$last" = to the content after the ":" e.g "Pass".

I'v looked around on google for about 2 hours and found nothing that works.
Hope you can help!

Comment: You googled, and you never found anything like `list($first, $last) = explode(':', $line);`?

Comment: That simple.... Nope I did not see anything like that during my time with google.

Comment: no-one's perfect, so well done for posting your question even though you risked being downvoted by a obvious loser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list` & `explode` -

```
$str = "User:Pass";

list($first, $last) = explode(':', $str);
```